# how to get html file into code in python?

Tags: python, sockets

how to get html file into python code using socket. I was able to implement using the requests library. However, it needs to be rewritten to sockets. I don’t understand how. The implementation code through requests will be below. I will also leave pathetic attempts to implement via a socket using Google. However, the decision is not at all correct. ! (Help implement using sockets.

```
import requests

reg_get = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.blog/")
text = reg_get.text
print(text)
```

```
import socket
request = b"GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: https://stackoverflow.blog/\n\n"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("https://stackoverflow.blog/", 80))
s.send(request)
result = s.recv(10000)
while (len(result) > 0):
    print(result)
    result = s.recv(10000)
```

After seeing the comments and listening to you. I have rewritten the following code. However, I never got the html. And I received information about the site. How do I get html structure in python

```
import socket
import ssl

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
request = "GET /r/AccidentalRenaissance/comments/8ciibe/mr_fluffies_betrayal/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.reddit.com\r\n\r\n"

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
s = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname = "www.reddit.com")

s.connect(("www.reddit.com", 443))
s.sendall(request.encode())

contest = s.recv(1024).decode()

s.close()
print(contest)
```

result

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-control: private, s-maxage=0, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-store
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Sun, 03 Oct 2021 03:34:25 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Vary: Accept-Encoding, Accept-Encoding
```

Comment: For one thing, leave off `https://` from the host name.  For another thing, https is port 443, not 80.

Answer (score 1):

A URL is composed of a protocol, a hostname, an optional port, and an optional path.  In the URL `http://stackoverflow.blog/` , https is the protocol, stackoverflow.blog is the hostname, and no port or path is provided.  For http, the port defaults to 80 and the path defaults to /.   When using sockets, first establish a connection to the host at the port using **connect** then **send** an HTTP command to retrieve the page on the path.  The HTTP command to retrieve the page is "GET /"   and **receive** the response from the server.

Note that I used http instead of https because https adds security set up and negotiation to the above that occurs once the **connect** is done but before the "GET /" is done.  It is quite complicated and a good reason to use Requests instead of trying to implement it yourself.  If you don't want to use Requests but don't want to go down to the level of sockets, take a look at urllib3